# A Datetime without time without string.format

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, datetime

I have a `DataTable` coming from a stored procedure which I'm writing to an excel file. There's a column with a `DateTime` datatype, and looking at the values in there, they're just generic dates with the time stamp.

I've tried using the `DateTime.Date` property, but that still gives me a time stamp. Further, I've tried to create a new `DateTime` object using the `year,month,day` constructor but it still adds a time stamp:

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime(oldDate.Year, oldDate.Month, oldDate.Day);
```

I'm trying to keep the column datatype to `DateTime` but remove the time stamp, so this rules out `ToString("")` formatting. Is there another way?

Comment: How about `DateTime.ToShortDateString`?

Comment: @Eugène This property just set it's time part to midnight. It doesn't/can't delete it's time part at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `DateTime` always contains a date and a time portion. If you use the `Date` property it returns a new `DateTime` where the time is `0:00:00` so midnight at the same day. You want a string representation of the datetime without the time.

You can use [`DateTime.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string result = oldDate.ToString("d"); // uses current culture's date format
```

or

```
string result = oldDate.ToShortDateString(); // same as above
```

or

```
string result = oldDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"); // custom format
```

**Edit**: "so this rules out `ToString("")` formatting. Is there another way?"

No, because of the reason mentioned above.

It's important to separate the data from how it is displayed. If you need to display it without time use the code above, you can store the original `DateTime` variable for future processing, select it again from database or use `DateTime.Parse`/`DateTime.ParseExcact` to get a `DateTime` from the string.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean time part with *timestamp*, a `DateTime` instance *always* have both date and time part. [`DateTime.Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) just sets the time value set to midnight.

You can get it's string representation if you want only it's `Date` part. You can get [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [custom date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `DateTime.ToString()` method.

*Usually*, you can use [`ShortDatePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get only string representation of `Date` part which uses [standard `"d"` format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#ShortDate) of your `CurrentCulture`.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d");
```

There is a proposal for `System.Date` and `System.Time` types for .NET Framework in [dotnet/corefx on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) page by the way.

- [Proposal: `System.Date` type](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/700)

Answer (score 2):

The 'problem' is that there is no `Date` struct in .NET, you only have a `DateTime` struct. That will always contain both date and time. You can only *format* it as date.

Or, you could of course write your own `struct` containing only the date part, or give up and use `string.Format` to format it as a date (possibly using the short date string `d`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();`